# Pass extra parameters along with the HttpPostedFileBase object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

In my MVC app, I have an upload View with GET and POST actions.

the question is how can I pass extra data to the POST Action along with the HttpPostedFileBase object, e.g., some ID for example.

Answer (score 4):

You just pass it as an additional parameter

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type='text' id='txtId' name='id'/>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string id) {

  if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
  }

  return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

}

Comment: Thanks Ryand, the Id parameter originally arriving from the GET action as a QueryString, should I pass it to the ViewData dictionary and render it as a hidden field in the View?

Comment: are you using the default route of controller/action/id?  Instead of a query string you could pass it as the id part of the route.  So your get would be "public ActionResult Upload(string id)" and the [httppost] would be "public actionresult(httppostedfilebase file, string id)